# How to do an inverse orderNorm transformation (bestNormalize package) from a GAMLSS object?

Tags: transformation, inverse, gamlss

My `y` variable (`n=30,000`) is distributed with very heavy tails (both positive and negative), for which the `fitDist` GAMLSS function selects the ST4 family.

I tried to assess a GAMLSS-based regression with an explanatory variable `x` (pb smoothing), but tails on `y` are so heavy that convergence does not reach after 50 cycles, even after refit (`time consuming+++`).

Therefore, I normalized `y` using the `orderNorm` transformation (`bestNormalize` package), which allowed to easily and quickly reach convergence, and then to predict the fitted value from the GAMLSS object.

However, these fitted "`orderNormalized`" values are a GAMLSS object, and thus cannot be inversed using the predict function from `bestNormalize` (since this latter seems to not recognize a GAMLSS object).

My question: is it possible, whatever the means, to apply an inverse `orderNorm` transformation to fitted values from a GAMLSS object?

Comment: An example would be helpful. The answer posted below is not helpful in my opinion because no example is given in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [vignette for `bestNormalize`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bestNormalize/vignettes/bestNormalize.html) has a similar example, using `lm` instead of GAMLSS. See the application section of the vignette. Once you have run the normalization procedure, you should be able to repeat and invert the transformation with the `predict` function.

The key is storing a transformation object as an R object that can then be fed into the `predict` (or rather, the `predict.bestNormalize`) function.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to get confused about on what to use the predict function, so I list here the steps without code (as there is no example in the question):

```
1) transposeObj = orderNorm(data$outputvariable)
2) fitObj = gamlls(transposeObj$x.t ~., data)
3) pred   = predict(fitObj, type = 'response')
4) inversedpredictions = predict(transposeObj, newdata = pred, inverse = TRUE)
```

In plain text, you normalize your data, fit a model, make predictions with the fit, and then predict on the predictions with the normalization object obtained from orderNorm.

Comment: Thank you Brigitte! The trick was the 'type', which is set by default to 'link' (see 'predict.gamlss' function from the gamlss package) but that we had to set to 'response'.